# using dask without > client = Client()

Tags: python, dask

about dask.

I want to read parquet file as df and run groupby function

my question is why should I run this code before?

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client()
client
```

and not just

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
        
df = dd.read_parquet(r'C:\Users\ggg\mis_1.parquet')
g=df.groupby('id')['id'].count().compute()
```

for me it work better without client

Comment: they should do the exact same thing. if a client does not already exist, dask.dataframe will create one for you. what do you mean when you say it works better?

Comment: better= faster.  and if I begin with client = Client() sometimes I get error for the same code

Comment: if you can post a [mre] demonstrating this it might make for a useful/interesting performance [issue for dask](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues). If you're actually getting errors setting up Client() this would be another one to make sure you can reprroduce. These should be identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read this page comparing the schedulers: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/scheduler-overview.html

If you don't have a `client`, you will use the default scheduler for your operation, which will be the threaded one for dataframe operations. If it extremely low-overhead, and avoids memory copies by charing the same memory space within a process. However, it isn't as smart, and will work very poorly for GIL-holding functions. If it works well for you, please use it!

The distributed scheduler provides many more options. You can choose your thread/process mix, or even have all the scheduler and threads in-process (which should perform about as well as the simple threaded scheduler. In addition, it provides more control over memory management and diagnostics via the dashboard. Of course, this is your only option if you actually need to distributed your compute over multiple machines. This options is *usually* the better choice, so it is generally recommended. However, `Client()` only gives you the default options, which might not be optional.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check it so I run many functions+compute() on 100 M rows table. with client(+ options) and without .

I didn't find any function that run better with Client() .
Not only that, in some cases after Client() I couldn't do things that worked good before.

I run the code in my own laptop and not in the cloud , maybe that's the reason ...